# Why program crashes after fscanf

Tags: c, file, while-loop, scanf, function-definition

> I'am trying to read a data from a textfile with fscanf but after readData function program is crashing. It's not entering the loop statement. In the console there is just printing data is read. When i tried to reading data in main it's working but i need to read in function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void readData(int array[10][3]);

int main(void)
{
    int data[10][3],i;
    
    readData(data);
    
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d \n",data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2]);
    }
}

void readData(array[10][3])
{
    int i;
    
    FILE *ptr = fopen("phonedata.txt","r");
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is no file");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data is read");
    }
    
    while(fscanf(ptr, "%d %d %d",&array[i][0],&array[i][1],array[i][2]) != EOF);
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there is more data in the file than your array can contain? Also if there is an error opening file, you are printing a message, but still trying to read it

Comment: It is recommended to add error message in question.

Comment: My guess is the file isn't opened, the `printf` is buffered because no newline so you don't see it in the fraction of a second before passing a NULL pointer to `fscanf`.

Comment: You have a semicolon after the `while` statement, so `i++` is not in the loop.

Comment: Oh, and `i` is uninitialized so if the file was opened you could be trying to read that data to anywhere.

Comment: Please add the line `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` after the line `printf("There is no file");`. You will have to add `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to use the function `exit`. That should make it clear whether the file is being successfully opened or not.

Comment: You should also tell the compiler about the array _type_ in `void readData(array[10][3])`, like so: `void readData(int array[10][3])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you forgot to specify the type of the parameter in the function definition

```
void readData(array[10][3])
```

you need to write

```
void readData(int array[10][3])
```

Within the function you are using the uninitialized variable `i`.

```
int i;
```

You have to write

```
int i = 0;
```

You have also to remove the semicolon after the while loop

```
    while(fscanf(ptr, "%d %d %d",&array[i][0],&array[i][1],array[i][2]) != EOF);
```

And it is better to write the condition like

```
    while( i < 10 && fscanf(ptr, "%d %d %d",&array[i][0],&array[i][1],array[i][2]) == 3)
```

And you need to place the while loop in the else statement

```
else
{
    printf("Data is read");

    while( i < 10 && fscanf(ptr, "%d %d %d",&array[i][0],&array[i][1],array[i][2]) == 3)
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

And you should return from the function the number of "rows" filled.

And before exiting the function the file must be closed.

```
fclose( ptr );
```

Comment: thank you soo much. I solve it with your help